# Is it possible to add a new TFS User Story to the top of the backlog via the REST api?

Tags: api, rest, tfs

We have an integration that adds TFS 2018 user stories to a Team via rest api. Currently the newly created user story goes to the bottom of the backlog. Is there a way to have it get added to the top of the backlog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is no such way to do this.

The sequence of items on each backlog is determined according to where you have added the items or moved the items on the page. As you drag and drop items within the backlog list, a background process updates the **Stack Rank** (Agile and CMMI processes) or Backlog Priority (Scrum process) fields. **These fields are used by the system** to track the relative ranking of items on the product, feature, epic, or other portfolio backlog.

> The **preferred method** for bulk edit is to use multi-select to **move
>   items to the top, bottom, or specific position within the page**. If you
>   must perform a bulk edit of one of the backlog order fields to get a
>   large number of work items in the priority order you want, use Excel.
>   You can export a query containing the backlog items, update either the
>   Backlog Priority or Stack Rank fields, and then publish your changes.

You could find this info in our official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-overview?view=azure-devops#backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-order). It's not able to do this via the Rest API.